# HTTPS request failed because of Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 only on iOS14.6

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, networking

everyone , Recently I update my iphone 12pro max system to iOS14.6 system , One of the HTTPS request connect to our server works fine on iOS14.5.1 and eariler iOS versions, but it fails only on iOS14.6,the error message shows like below :

`Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "此服务器的证书无效。您可能正在连接到一个伪装成“a.b.c.com”的服务器，这会威胁到您的机密信息的安全。" UserInfo={NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=<SecTrustRef: 0x28103fd50>, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://a.b.c.com/path/to/specific/work/get, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://a.b.c.com/path/to/specific/work/get, NSLocalizedDescription=此服务器的证书无效。您可能正在连接到一个伪装成“a.b.c.com”的服务器，这会威胁到您的机密信息的安全。}`

but we had double check the certicicate of the service, pretty sure it's ok, and the certificate was approved by go_daddy, but it only happens on iOS14.6, and now all of our user update to iOS14.6 encountered this problem, anyone can help, thanks a million.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by go_daddy, certificate generated during 4.21.2021 and 4.27.2021 by go_daddy only contains 2 SCT log oprators, iOS14.6 requires 3 operators. Just ask go_daddy recreate a certificate and everything will be ok.

more info here:https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/681207